# execute for-each in XSLT no looping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HSoThueDTu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://kekhaithue.gdt.gov.vn/TKhaiThue">
  <HSoKhaiThue>
    <TTinChung>
      <TTinDVu>
        <maDVu>01</maDVu>
        <tenDVu>Number 01</tenDVu>
      </TTinDVu>
      <TTinDVu>
        <maDVu>02</maDVu>
        <tenDVu>Number 02</tenDVu>
      </TTinDVu>
      <TTinDVu>
        <maDVu>03</maDVu>
        <tenDVu>Number 03</tenDVu>
      </TTinDVu>
    </TTinChung>
  </HSoKhaiThue>
</HSoThueDTu>
```

I am trying to print content using XSL tranform to HTML. But i got stuck when using for-each

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='TTinDVu']">
```

But it have no loop. 
I try a different way:
    
It get same problem

My xslt look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="viVNFormat" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        ...
        <xsl:for-each select="/HSoThueDTu/HSoKhaiThue/TTinChung">
           ...
        </xsl:for-each>
        ...
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input XML has a default namespace. This needs to be declared in your XSLT stylesheet, too - and if you refer to input elements, you have to *prefix* them.

You have shown only a snippet of your stylesheet - so it is impossible to decide where exactly you went wrong. There might be other causes of error in your code.

Remove the `/` in front of `tk:HSoThueDTu` in the `xsl:for-each` part.

**Stylesheet** (a complete example that actually *does* something)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tk="http://kekhaithue.gdt.gov.vn/TKhaiThue">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:decimal-format name="viVNFormat" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="tk:HSoThueDTu/tk:HSoKhaiThue/tk:TTinChung">
           <xsl:text>Found </xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="count(tk:TTinDVu)"/>
           <xsl:text> TTinDVu elements!</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Found 3 TTinDVu elements!
```

Comment: tks. But it only execute for first loop and stopped after

Comment: This is exactly right. There is only **one** `TTinChung` element in your input XML. Since you are looping over exactly this, one iteration is to be expected.

Comment: I'm mark it to the best answer. In my case, it is not exactly same to my question. My XML file have many elements and i have to reduce the content - make it easy to understant my problem. Anyway, tks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a shortcut for your default namespace `http://kekhaithue.gdt.gov.vn/TKhaiThue` in your stylesheet, say `xmlns:kek="http://kekhaithue.gdt.gov.vn/TKhaiThue"`

then, refer to the nodes applying the prefix `kek:`, e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/kek:HSoThueDTu/kek:HSoKhaiThue/kek:TTinChung">
```

Summing up, the following stylesheet should be used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kek="http://kekhaithue.gdt.gov.vn/TKhaiThue">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="viVNFormat" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="kek:HSoThueDTu/kek:HSoKhaiThue/kek:TTinChung/kek:TTinDVu">
            <xsl:copy>
            <!-- do something here -->
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have tried it before but it executed only one loop!!

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh: Like Matthias said.. That is correct. You are looping over an element that has once occurence..

Comment: @Vũ Tuấn Anh: You should not be rude when people try to help you. Use less exclamation marks - especially because you are the one that is wrong.

Comment: edited my post, the loop should be up to `kek:TTinDVu`.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML has a default namespace `xmlns="http://kekhaithue.gdt.gov.vn/TKhaiThue"`. Meaning all unprefixed nodes in you source XML belong to that namespace. You should also declare the namespace in your XSLT with a prefix. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mypref="http://kekhaithue.gdt.gov.vn/TKhaiThue">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="viVNFormat" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        ...
        <xsl:for-each select="mypref:HSoThueDTu/mypref:HSoKhaiThue/mypref:TTinChung/mypref:TTinDVu">
           ...
        </xsl:for-each>
        ...
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** You should learn more about namespaces and namespace prefixes, if you do not understand them, you will be back asking more questions about it.

Comment: Nothings are gonna changed

Comment: @MathiasMüller: Correct, just adjusted it. But if he is going to add elements into the XSLT, he needs to add them also to the default namespace or add all the elements into the mypref prefixed namespace.. But I guess we will get a new question when he rans into it..